# Compile Error: unexpected token: public at line 302

Tags: apex, compile-error

In order to do a mass update to data I commented out code and deployed to production.  Now I'm un-commenting the code to redeploy and I'm getting the compile error.  SecondSection is definitely declared and I'm in desperate need of help.  What can cause the public class to throw a compile error?

public with sharing class QuoteImplementationController {

```
    public FirstSection firstSection { get; set; }  
    public SecondSection secondSection { get; set; }
```

...

```
    public class SecondSection {
```

Comment: Because you have commented out code and the bracketing, ; etc are out of place. Work your way back and ensure every bracket, ; , etc have a matching opening bracket, etc. You will have to show all your code for us to help. Right now it is a basic debugging thing...

Comment: We need a code's snippet bigger to help you